# mySQL Find consecutive dates

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

Given a datababase with the following columns (int)id, (DATE)beginDay, (DATE)endDay

find consecutive days exactly 1 DAY apart, and output the beginDay and endDay

i.e

```
 1 | 2011-01-01    2011-01-02
 2 | 2011-01-02    2011-01-03
 3 | 2011-01-03    2011-01-07
 4 | 2011-02-12    2011-02-13
```

print

```
2011-01-01 2011-01-03
2011-02-12 2011-02-13
```

Comment: I'm confused.  What happened to 2011-01-07?  What is the logic for the second row?

Comment: The integer to the left is the id column, it is somewhat useless just for good practice

Comment: The second row is the endDay, so similiar to a clock in schedule. The 2011-01-07 would signify clocking out on that date. I am looking only for sequences of consecutive dates, and then returning the first and last day of the sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem.  You can solve it by subtracting a sequence of values from the date -- the difference is constant when the dates are consecutive.

If you are looking at `beginday`, you can use:

```
select min(beginday), max(beginday)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by beginday) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by beginday - interval seqnum day;
```

If you care about `endday`, you can just use:

```
select t.*
from t
where endday = begindate + interval 1 day;
```